# I get this error when I want to know my Laravel version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-9

I have a project that I need to upgrade Laravel version. I did not write this project myself. Now when I type `php artisan --version` to find out the Laravel version of the project, I get the following error.

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\USER\Desktop\omnicourse_creator_panel-main/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\USER\Desktop\omnicourse_creator_panel-main\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\omnicourse_creator_panel-main/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\USER\Desktop\omnicourse_creator_panel-main\artisan on line 18
```

Do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: First install required packages, go to Laravel project and run this command from terminal  `composer install` after installing packages run this command `php artisan --version`

Comment: I wrote the command as you said, but then something like this happens. I'm a bit new to this stuff. `Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`                     Gave 10 problems but I can't fit them here.

Comment: There are a conflict between new Laravel version dependences  and the current app version open composer.json file and search about `laravel/framework`  to view the Laravel version.

Comment: `"laravel/framework": "^7.29"` this is how it shows the Laravel version of the project. What should I understand here?

Comment: Check your composer.lock file, it will show you the exact version installed

Comment: Make sure you have a php version that is compatible with 7.29.  It needs greater than php 7.2.5 but might not be compatible with 8 or 8.1

Comment: @Snapey I updated my php version and I think I've made some progress on this. I made my php version 8.1.9. I also updated the composer to the latest version. There seems to be no problem between the php version and the laravel version. What do you think I should do now?

Comment: You still get the error?

Comment: @Snapey yes I'm still getting errors and I think things got more confused.

Answer (score 0):

use the command 'composer update --ignore-platform-reqs' to update all the packages regardless of the differences in their versions.

Comment: I updated my php version and I think I've made some progress on this. I made my php version 8.1.9. However, when I run the command you said, I get an error like this. `In Factory.php line 656:

  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex
  tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.`  What do you think I should do in this situation?